# Data.Matrix error - NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, csv, nas, coercion

I am required to build returns given Bob Shiller's updated data, which I have downloaded and imported in R to start working with it.

Since my professor speaks at the speed of light and then keeps answering "wake up" when I try to ask him something about the program, I figured I would ask it here, hoping to finally find an answer.

So:

I import the list of data in `R`, by using the function:

```
data_ie_2017 = read.table(file = "ie_data_2017.csv", skip = 7, 
stringAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

(Note: the file came in `.xls` format, I have converted it into `.csv` simply by "saving as", maybe that could cause trouble, I have no idea since I'm a noob with this program).

Then, mindlessly copying what the professor did in class, I try to convert it into a data.matrix, to then convert it into a time series and finally into a data.frame. Therefore, I try to use the function:

```
data_ie_2017_matrix = data.matrix(data_ie_2017[1:1760, 1:11]
```

(why do even have to specify the rows/columns? Doesn't R just read the whole file?)

At this point, instead of getting my `data.matrix`, I get 11 warnings, all equal one to the other:

```
In data.matrix(data_ie_2017) : NAs introduced by coercion.
```

Can anyone help me understand WHY I'm getting the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Hard to diagnose without a sample of the input data, but, is every column of the data numeric? `data.matrix` attempts to convert the entire data frame to numeric. If some of the columns are not numeric (if they have columns of categorial labels or string data), they can't be converted to numeric and `NA`s will be generated. Looks like this is happening in 11 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought it might be the non-numerical values, and in fact in the .csv file some columns are "numbers" and some are "general", such as the last column that has 25-30 entries that are just "NA". However, our professor provided us with an outdated version of the data set (stopping at 2016, December), and when I do the data matrix with HIS data, it works perfectly fine, even though the format is exactly the same (some numbers and some generals), it just has less data! That made me think that there must be something else...

Comment: As for the actual data, you can find it by googling "bob Schiller data" and its the first link on the website